# Python - passing Beautiful Soup ouput to a variable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Python noob here: this works nicely to extract the text from the URL but I don't understand the invalid syntax error it throws:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> with open("https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/xml/TWOAT.xml") as markup:
...     soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())
... text = soup.get_text()
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    text = soup.get_text()
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print(text)
```

It gives this output, exactly what I want:

```
Atlantic Tropical Weather Outlook
000
ABNT20 KNHC 081908
TWOAT 
Tropical Weather Outlook...Retransmitted
NWS National Hurricane Center Miami FL
200 PM EDT Thu Aug 8 2019
For the North Atlantic...Caribbean Sea and the Gulf of Mexico:
Tropical cyclone formation is not expected during the next 5 days.
$$
Forecaster Pasch
>>>
```

Comment: The python interactive shell prints `...` at the start of the line to indicate that you're in an indented block.  To end the block, you have to enter a blank line first.  That same code would have worked just fine in a standalone script.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you get is because you didn't press Enter twice after `soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())` part and python thinks you are still under the indentation. But even if you do it you will get another error because you try to open remote location as a file. It won't work.

Try using requests to fetch the data:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/xml/TWOAT.xml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
text = soup.get_text()
print(text)
```